# Laravel not creating response custom header

Tags: laravel, http-headers, response-headers

When request is json all ok I got my 'xxx' header, but when it's direct request to page - my header does't exists in response.

I tried any variation of `response()->header`, `response('content',200,['xxx'=>'xxx'])` and no success

My code in controller:

```
return $request->wantsJson()
            ? response([
                'html'          => view('components.tarif-list', compact('tarifs'))->render(),
                'pagination'    => $tarifs->appends(request()->query())->links()->toHtml(),
                'head'          => $seo_block,
                'stats'         => $stats
            ])->header('xxx','xxx')
            : response(view('home',compact('tarifs','seo_block'))->render())->header('xxx','xxx');
```

home.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')
    <x-filters/>
    <div id="head" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        @if(!empty($seo_block))
        {!! $seo_block !!}
            @elseif($tarifs->isEmpty())
            empty
            @else
            hello
        @endif
    </div>
    {{$tarifs->appends(request()->query())->links()}}
    <table id="tarif-list" class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <x-tarif-list :tarifs="$tarifs"/>
    </table>
    {{$tarifs->appends(request()->query())->links()}}
@endsection
```

Comment: I can't see any code, that you are retrieving the response header?

Comment: why I need retrieve it? I waiting it in http response headers

Comment: You need to somehow be sure that it's retrieved from the controller, So either you need to dump it in the blade file or see it in browser header response.

Comment: Hm.. I have no idea how to dump it in blade

Comment: \request()->headers->get('xxx')

Comment: why request() if we setting response headers

Comment: anyway it dumps null

Answer (score 0):

If you dd this line of code

```
response(view('home',compact('tarifs','seo_block'))->render())->header('xxx','xxx')
```

You will see this response

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag {#2878
  #computedCacheControl: array:2 [
    "no-cache" => true
    "private" => true
  ]
  #cookies: []
  #headerNames: array:3 [
    "cache-control" => "Cache-Control"
    "date" => "Date"
    "xxx" => "xxx"
  ]
  #headers: array:3 [
    "cache-control" => array:1 [
      0 => "no-cache, private"
    ]
    "date" => array:1 [
      0 => "Thu, 07 May 2020 11:27:31 GMT"
    ]
    "xxx" => array:1 [
      0 => "xxx"
    ]
  ]
  #cacheControl: []
}
```

So the keys are there, But how you retrieving the headers in your blade file?

Comment: Im not retrieving it in blade.

Comment: yes I see headers in dd, but why I can't get it in response?

Comment: Where you are using that response? Can you share your code?

Comment: you mean blade template?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in controller before response was `dump()` and as we know headers must be first content at page.

But why php or laravel does't tell about it.
Default php warning for it:

```
PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by..........
```